# Error when running project c# music player

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-code

Hi this is a simple music player app that I have developed using c# following a YouTube video, it is right at the end and now the program will not run as it should which is to play the selected music as you can see from the attached picture that error is "Error   CS0103  The name 'axWindowsMediaPlayer' does not exist in the current context"

not sure if is it a compiler error

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MusicPlayer
{
    public partial class MusicPlayer : Form
    {
        public MusicPlayer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Create Global variables of string type array to save the titles or name the of the songs and the path (location) of the songs 
        string[] paths, files;

        private void btnSelectSongs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // code for selecting songs 
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

            // code for selecting multiple tracks 
            ofd.Multiselect = true;
            ofd.Filter = "All Supported Audio | *.mp3; *.wma | MP3s | *.mp3 | WMAs | *.wma";

            if (ofd.ShowDialog()==System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                files = ofd.SafeFileNames; // this is to save name of the songs in the files array
                paths = ofd.FileNames; // this is to save the paths/location of the songs in the path array

                // after that we display the music titles in the listbox
                for (int i = 0; i <files.Length; i++)
                {

                    listBoxSongs.Items.Add(files[i]); // this displays the songs in the list box
                }
            }
        }

        private void listBoxSongs_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // code for playing the sellected music 
           axWindowsMediaPlayer.URL = paths[listBoxSongs.SelectedIndex];
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // code for closing the app 
            this.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

[This is how the error looks on visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihpZd.png)

Comment: did you mean.. `AxWindowsMediaPlayer`?

Comment: hi I have tried the following

Comment: AxWindowsMediaPlayer.URL still showing the error

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e628d9/playing-audio-and-video-files-using-C-Sharp/

Comment: Been there, and as far as I remember the key was to reference some Windows DLL. However, since there is NAudio (https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) , I would recommend using that. I have sucesssfully replaced the Windows Media Player in my project (https://github.com/suterma/Replayer) with that. If you need, you could also dig in the history of my project to find the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

write click on media player>properties>name. Check name of the player and then use that name in your code.